# Grails searchable component option

Tags: grails, searchable, compass-lucene

Where are two domains

```
class State {
  String name

  static searchable = {
    only: 'name'
  }
}

class Region {
  State state
  String name

  static searchable = {
    state component: true
    only: 'name'
  }
}
```

I want to find only regions by region name or all regions of state by state name.
States should not be in search result.

How I have to change the code?
PS
I know how to find objects by gorm. I wrote just simple example of code. I need lucene for featured search

Comment: Can you paste your search code you have written.

Comment: just for test: searchableService.search(name)

Answer (score 0):

Region by region name
In SearchableService

```
def search(String state){
 def stateSearch = State.findByName(region);
 return stateSearch
 }
```

Find all region of state by state
In searchableService

```
def regionSearch(String region, String state){
 def state = state.findByName(state);
 def region = Region.findByState(state);
return return
}
```

Hopefully this work.If not, please paste your code in the service.

Comment: I know how to find objects by gorm. I wrote just simple example of code. I need lucene for featured search

Comment: Then you should have stated that.

Comment: What do you think, why I use searchable? Because I need flexible search